# Inject env variables from env.local into docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, twilio, ngrok

I'm new to docker and have env variables from env.local I want to add to my container. How would I go about using the docker CLI to add these in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an env file when using docker-compose with the `--env-file` flag.

See: [Docker Documentation: Environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option)

```
docker compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev config
```